# how to call function using jasmine in phonegap with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, jasmine

i'm using jasmine for testing.

there are simple angular module and array like this

```
var todoApp = angular.module('todoApp', []);

todoApp.controller('todoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.todoList = [
    {done : true, title : 'Item 1'},
    {done : false, title : 'Item 2'}, 
    {done : false, title : 'Item 3'}
    ];

    $scope.addNewTodo = function (newTitle) {
        $scope.todoList.push({done: false, title : newTitle});
        $scope.newTitle = '';
    }
}
```

and i would like to push new item through addNewTodo function in jasmine test

so i wrote jasmine test code like this

```
describe('angularTdd', function () {
    beforeEach(module('todoApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('todoCtrl', {$scope:scope});
    }));

    it('addNewTodo should add newTitle', function () {
        spyOn(scope, 'addNewTodo');
        scope.addNewTodo('Item 4');
        expect(scope.addNewTodo).toHaveBeenCalled();
        // alert(scope.todoList[0].title);
        expect(scope.todoList.length).toEqual(4);
    });
});
```

i called addNewTodo function with 'Item 4' argument and

```
expect(scope.addNewTodo).toHaveBeenCalled() line is passed during test
```

so i expected todoList.length as 4.

but todoList.length won't be changed as 4. it's still 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you spy on something, it will not call the original method with its actual code unless you specify it explicitly with `.andCallThrough()` method. The `it` part of your test would look like this:

```
it('addNewTodo should add newTitle', function () {
    spyOn(scope, 'addNewTodo').andCallThrough(); //<--- this is important
    scope.addNewTodo('Item 4');
    expect(scope.addNewTodo).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // alert(scope.todoList[0].title);
    expect(scope.todoList.length).toEqual(4);
});
```